# How to view html and css associated with shadow dom

Tags: javascript, html, dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I am using a @NgComponent of angular-dart to create a custom html(shadown dom) element.

Now i am programatically changing the html associated with the component. But as i am not able to see associated html in the browser. So i am not able to debug the change in html.

I want to know how do we enable displaying of html associated with custom html(shadown dom) element. Is there a javascript that enables this?

I am using Dartium to view the output.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome allow you to view shadow dom?

Comment: My code doesnt work in Chrome. I think i have to do some dart2js stuff. So i am using Dartium and that doesnt display shadown dom html.

Comment: Can't you log the created dom to the console before putting it in the shadow dom? Sorry, not familiar with Dartium.

Comment: Can be done, but doesnt look most ideal solution. I have seen support for viewing the html for shadow dom as a dropdown under the custom tag. But dont know how to enable that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the Shadow DOM in Dartium and Chrome, you must enable it in DevTools.

1. Right-click on your page and select "Inspect Element" to bring up DevTools
2. Click the Settings gear in the top-right corner of the DevTools window
3. Under the "Elements" heading, find and enable the "Show Shadow DOM" checkbox.

Now you should see #document-fragments in the Elements pane of DevTools.  Those are your Shadow DOM.